# Object CouchDoc members are inaccessilbe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, couchdb

So im using https://github.com/eddelplus/CornerCouch/blob/master/angular-cornercouch.js
to access my CouchDB. If i print the object it shows me the whole thing.

> ```
> console.log($scope.item);
> console.log($scope.item.author);
> ```

[image: Inaccessible members]

but if i print out one member variable of this object that i know it is there id tell me undefined.

My guess is it has smth to do with prototyping!

What could this be.

Comment: did you make the console.log statements just behind each other?

Comment: //.... function ...
            var doc = this;
            return $http(extendJSONP(config)).success( function (data) {
                ng.copy(data, doc);
});
I Think angular.copy might also play a role in it

Comment: Ok with an interval off two seconds it works. but how can it be that it got the data and it is not yet copied?!

Comment: it can be because you are printing an object to the console. if the console is very cool and clever it would be possible that the console shows the live data and not only the data at the moment you are logging the object. if you try to log a specific property (e.g. author) only the value will be printed and is not updated if the data are arriving form the server. i guess you are calling $scope.item.load() right? this is asynchronous. but it doesn't matter for angular if you are using ng-bind or ng-model. angular will update the view if the data are arrived.

Comment: if you want be sure to access the property first if the data is arrived you should write: $scope.item.load().success(function(data){console.log(data.author)});

Comment: ok, seems my assumption about the chrome console is right: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2408-Chrome-Dev-Tools-Live-Update-In-The-JavaScript-Console-Is-Confusing.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info Michael. That really explains some things. One correction the load() function needs an id otherwise it will return the db object. $scope.item.load(id).success(function(data){console.log(data.author)});

Answer (score 0):

As Michael mentioned, this is do to the asynchronous nature by which you get $scope.item.  I ran into a similar (or the same?) problem and fixed it by calling $scope.$digest().  The documentation says that you normally don't need to call [$digest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24digest) explicitly, because [$apply(expr)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply) will execute $digest for you, but $scope.$digest() is just simpler (at least, it's what makes the most sense in this case).

So, just to clarify: The reason $scope.item was printed to the console was because $scope.item was defined, even if it was empty at the time of being called.  However, at the time of being called, $scope.item has no properties, so $scope.item.author is undefined.

Here is an example from my code.  The idea should be similar for you (I am using the kanso db package).

```
db.getList('problems', 'questionsByBranch', 'questions', function (err, data) {
    if (err) 
        return alert(err);

    $scope.questionsByBranch = data;    
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: when i call digest it runs into an error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress. i resolved it as Michael suggested, by putting the functionality into the success clojure. Not the best solution because im calling the object load() twice, but its working.